# differing $request_time and $upstream_reponse_time in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx with some backend hosts.

I've created custom log format with TR:$request_time US:$upstream_response_time` to watch delivery of the requests.

I've got log line (serving CSS file from backing) with lines `TR:2.410 US:0.012` , which probably means "the request has been serverd by backend host in 0.012  second, but nginx itself took 2.410 seconds to serve the request".

**Question: Does it mean that the receiving host received response more than 100times slower than the originating machine generated it? How this can happen? (other than the slow line)**

The receiving machine of this log is my laptop located in different city (10ms TTL from server to the laptop). I'm quite surprised because for most request, the `$request_time` and `$upstream_response_time` are usually very close to each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430951/why-is-request-time-much-larger-than-upstream-response-time-in-nginx-access-log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592773/nginx-request-time-and-upstream-response-time-in-windows